# Assets\RayShooter.cs(10,19): error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Component.GetComponent<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage в чем ошибка?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу понять почему так.
Учу C# по книге "Unity в действии" Джозефа Хокинга.
В этом коде написано все так как в книжке

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class RayShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera _camera;

    void Start()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 point = new Vector3(
                _camera.pixelWidth / 2, _camera.pixelHeight / 2, 0);
            Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(point);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                StartCoroutine(SphereIndicator(hit.point));
            }
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator SphereIndicator(Vector3 pos) {
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = pos;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        Destroy(sphere);
    }
}
```

но Unity все равно просит поставить `<аргумент>` после `GetComponent()`

Comment: Ну правильно просит. Разве он не должен быть заполнен?

Comment: Либо книжка устарела, либо там на js написано. Либо для юнити старых версий очень

Comment: Нужно указать тип компонента, который вы ищете. Что-то типа `_camera = GetComponent<Camera>();`, вместо `Camera` подставьте искомый тип, хотя это кажется нужный тип и есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы были как-то невнимательны. Там всё есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том, что в моем издании видимо не дописано <Camera>

Comment: Значит оно гиперстарое. Потому что у меня книги аж 2015 года. В любом случае в новых версиях (начиная с 5.5 точно) надо писать через дженерики

Comment: у меня второе издание 2019 года :)

Comment: ...... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯